# Hibernate 4.2, is many-to-one default cascade mapping none?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I saw many times that default hibernate `cascade` is `"none"`. I.e. if you omit `cascade` tag in xml mapping it's the same as `"none"`.

Today I observed strange behavior when class A that many-to-one to class B updated class B tables (and even dependent B's collections).

Adding `cascade="none"` fixed my issue.

But my question remains the same what is default cascade for many-to-one xml mapping in hibernate?

**UPDATE 6.05.20** I suspect that default `cascade` has some internal (not `none` state) and in that mode hibernate process objects with components (in hibernate terms). During debug session I observed a list of "manageable" objects that are unchanged but mark as "dirty" for some unknown reason.

**TL;DR**

Sample of xml mapping. AuditRecord is many-to-one to User class. Persistent of AuditRecord updates (sometimes!) User class and dependent collections.

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false" default-access="field">
    <class name="package.AuditRecord" table="audit_record">
        <id name="uuid" type="string">
            <column name="uuid" sql-type="char(32)" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="package.User" cascade="none">
            <column name="user_uuid" sql-type="char(32)" not-null="false" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="success" type="boolean" not-null="true"/>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Sample of Java code that actually persist `AuditRecord` class.

```
      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
      try {
          session.saveOrUpdate(pObject);
          session.flush();
          tx.commit();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          tx.rollback();
          ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed `B` in the same transaction and that flushing the session saves `B` because, well, `B` has been changed?

Comment: @Smutje 100%. I loaded `B` in session1 and create new object `A` and persisted it in new session2.

Comment: @Smutje Even if I changed smth in the instance of `B`. Why it was cascaded? Till today I suppose that global default `cascade` is `none`, but it more looks like `save-update` :)